# Checking If every row in table view have image hidden or not

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

Is there any way to check inside a function : `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` If rest of the rows ( instead of the first one ) have image hidden or not.

- If images of rows which are greater then `indexPath.row` - 0 are all hidden or not.
  So basically I would like to get the first row ( image ) of the table view hidden when the rest one are hidden as well. The simple check boxes.

This how I'm hiding them :

```
let row = indexPath.row

if row > 0 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    let currentCell = self.engineStatusTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DropDownViewCell
                    if !currentCell.checkMark.isHidden {
                        currentCell.checkMark.isHidden = true
                    } else {
                        currentCell.checkMark.isHidden = false
                    }
                })
            }
```

[image: Here is a visualization]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not a good idea to keep your state inside of cells.  Cells are reused and somewhat expensive to create, so you want to let UITableView control the creation and manage their reuse.

But, hopefully, your datasource knows if the checkmark is supposed to be hidden or not and you can ask it without having to create a cell to do that.

Comment: engineStatusTableView.cellForRow creates the cell and sets isHidden -- show us that code.

Comment: Yeah, got it - I've just created tmp variable. Back to the question, how could i know if every cell instead of first have hidden image ?

Comment: Expose a function in the datasource that takes an indexPath and implement that function so that it can answer without creating a cell